# Translate CancelableEvent to RX

Tags: c#, system.reactive

currently i try to get into thinking the Reactive Extensions way, by only send one way messages from components. But i still havent figuered out how to implement something with CancelableEventArgs that relies on the synchronous execution of the registered handlers into a solution that works with rx.

Example:

```
public void Delete()
{
    var deleteRequest = new DeleteServerRequest(_serverConfigurationMapper.Map(SelectedServer)); 
    _eventStream.Push(deleteRequest);
    if (!deleteRequest.Cancel)
        _serverConfigurationRepository.Delete(deleteRequest.Server);
}
```

In another class i register on the DeleteServerRequest and show a prompt so the user is able to cancel the deletion of the item.

```
_eventStream.Of<DeleteServerRequest>().Subscribe(
    req =>
      req.Cancel = DilaogResult.Yes != MessageBox.Show("Delte Server?", 
                                                       "Do you want to delete the server?",
                                                       MessageBoxButtons.YesNo))
```

How would i do something like this with only one directional messaging like in RX?

PS: 
The Delete method is the implementation of a command in a ViewModel, so i didn't want to bring UI-Framework code into it.
The EventHandler is in a controller, that only should show and close the different windows and dialogs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can do this, just move the cancellation down stream.

```
_eventStream.Of<DeleteServerRequest>()
  .Map(req => {
    req.Cancel = DialogResult.Yes != MessageBox.Show("Delete Server?", 
                                                       "Do you want to delete the server?",
                                                       MessageBoxButtons.YesNo));
    return req;
  })
  .Filter(x => !x.Cancel)
  .Publish().RefCount()
  .Subscribe(x => _serverConfigurationRepository.Delete(x.Server));
```

I'm personally not a big fan of the "merge all events into a single stream" approach and although it is valid I would create a stream specifically for deletions and then wrap the request creation in it as well. This will also help remove side effects that are being pulled into the Observable during its operation. In which case `Delete` would look like

```
public void Delete()
{
    _deleteStream.Push(SelectedServer);
}
```

And the stream would look like:

```
_deleteStream
  .Map(selected => new DeleteServerRequest(_serverConfigurationMapper.Map(selected)))
      .Map(req => {
        req.Cancel = DialogResult.Yes != MessageBox.Show("Delete Server?", 
                                                         "Do you want to delete the server?",
                                                           MessageBoxButtons.YesNo));
        return req;
      })
      .Filter(x => !x.Cancel)
      .Publish().RefCount()
      .Subscribe(x => _serverConfigurationRepository.Delete(x.Server));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but wouldn't i mix my UI code with behaviour if i move the call to the repository out of the viewmodel (Delete-Method) into the controller (event subscription) which should only control what dialogs to show?

Comment: Another problem i see with the solution you suggest is, if i have no subscription to the _deletestream the item wouldn't be delted. With my code, if i got no subscription, the item would still be delted. Is there a way to get the exact same behaviour?

Comment: @BoeseB You could split the stream up anyway you wanted really. if you wanted so that the subscribe (delete) occurs in the ViewModel and the message box shows in the controller.